# Git warnings when certain files have changed

Tags: git

When I "git pull" the project that I'm working on a ton of files sometimes come down from other developers' changes. I would like to be able to mark certain files that I want to be warned about that I might miss in the pages of text during the pull.

For example, if package.json has changed I know that I need to run "npm i" and if one the .sql files have changed I know that I need to run a script to update the DB schema. If I miss these then I can experience problems until I realize what has happened.

A couple of solutions that jump to mind:

- Wrap git in a script that does this. Yes, that would work but would be less portable as I'd have to carry that script from machine to machine and might forget to do it.
- Get into the habit of always running my post pull scripts even if they're not needed. This takes time.

The ideal solution would be able to modify the git config file either locally or globally to mark file patterns (same as .gitignore) so that after or during a pull action those files are highlighted for special attention.

Solutions?

Comment: You're after a post-checkout hook. You could simply make one that automatically does `npm i` when required, rather then just notifying you that you need to run it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [git hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). A hook is a script which git runs before or after a command; you can write your own. `post-checkout` or `post-merge` are probably the hooks to do what you're after, assuming every `pull` triggers one of those. As @meagar points out, you can write a script which checks for changes to specific files and then performs the required actions without too much trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody is recommending you to use gits hooks, but I would actually take a build system approach.

For example, if your package.json changes, make a rule on your Makefile that depends on that and the action is to execute the required command.

This way, your system dependencies do not depend on your version control system, and you always see it happening when you call make or whatever build system you use.

Comment: Agreed. The problem is not git per se but rather updating an installation. If you use make you should be aware though that make tracks changes by comparing the file date of output files against input files. For SQL there are generally no output files (don't even think of trying to use the sql file in your filesystem for this, it won't work because each database transaction will update its file date). For SQL you need to create dummy output files so that make knows that you've applied the changes or not.

Comment: slebetman, That is correct, you will need dummy files for those commands that do not produce output, but this is not something strange to the make world.